# Better ideas on how to Assigning Id dynamically in Javascript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

A lot of my PHP code creates a dynamic ID selector because I don't have the ID `attr` value until I execute the PHP code, so I am finding myself taking a shortcut and putting jquery javascript code as name of the ID being created.

So I want to know if there are other ways of doing it better. My current method works, but I know it's bad practice.

To illustrate what I am doing:

```
for ($x=0;$x>=10; $x++){
echo "...
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $( \"#dialog{$x}\" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: \"blind\",
        hide: \"explode\"
    });
    $( \"#opener{$x}\" ).click(function() {
      $( \"#dialog{$x}\" ).dialog( \"open\" );
        return false;
    });
    </script>
    ...";


  echo "<a id=\"opener{$x}\"> View Notes</a>";
  echo "<div id=\"dialog{$x}\">some data also dynamically generated depending on value of $x</div>";
}
```

Comment: You could change the javascript, there is no need to create 10 functions, but I guess that's optional.

Comment: Might want to post this over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try not to echo full `<script>`s, especially not ten of them. Do only echo the `10` inside a script and do the loop in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your HTML mark-up using classes and data attributes.

For example:

```
<a href="#" class="opener" data-id="1">View Notes</a>
<div class="notes" data-id="1">My notes here</div>

<a href="#" class="opener" data-id="2">View Notes</a>
<div class="notes" data-id="2">My other notes here</div>
```

Then write your JavaScript to take an array of options using class selectors.

```
$('.notes').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: "blind",
    hide: "explode"
});

$('.opener').click(function(e) {
    $('.notes[dataId==' + $(this).data('id')).dialog('open');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say, change the javascript and put it outside the loop.

Instead of putting a unique id you could put it as a class:

```
echo "<a id=\"opener{$x}\" class=\"myclass\"> View Notes</a>";
```

And then move the javascript outside the loop and just print it out normally.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $('.myclass').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode"
    });
$('.myclass').click(function() {
      $(this).dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

I hope you get my drift. But if there is something special why you are using id's, your code is fine.

**EDIT:** if that's all of your code and you decide you are going with classes instead, you won't need a loop to put all the id's out. But it might come in handy if you want to do something with that id later. Like sending it to the server side via an ajax post request.

Answer (score 0):

The way WordPress handles localization of JavaScript is by using an inline SCRIPT tag to set variables, which are then referenced in the external JS files.  This prevents having to place the whole script inline, while allowing passing of data between PHP and JavaScript.  Use can use this method to pass the total number to the JS script in the external file as the variable is declared globally.

For your example you would change the inline script to something like:

```
<script>
    var dialog_count = 10;
</script>
```

This sets the number of dialogs available, and move the dialog function into a JS file.  You would need to change your function to take a parameter of the index you want to register and then iterate through each of the indexes calling this function to register each index using the dialog_count value as the total.